# Should there be a separate tag for Minecraft questions related to snapshots?

Tags: discussion, tags

With every period of time when a new update is in the works for [Minecraft](http://minecraft.net), Mojang will often release 'snapshot' candidate versions on a weekly basis to test out any new features being added and to help bring any feedback. During these periods of time, there will also be new question on Arqade about Minecraft that are about one of these snapshots.

There certainly is nothing wrong with that, however there is one small thing that comes to mind. Should the major version ever be released, any new features that the question has been asking about may most likely have different functionality depending on the snapshot being used. If that were ever to happen, there's a chance that users who aren't aware of these snapshot versions may get confused considering that the said feature in the question is described differently as to how it would actually work after the snapshots.

Therefore, does that mean that there should be a separate tag to be used for questions referring to a snapshot version, such as [minecraft-snapshot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-snapshot)? Would there be any other implications involved in doing so?

**Would using this tag be viable?**

Comment: Please note that there is a pending synonym request for [minecraft-snapshots] on [minecraft], [see here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/minecraft/synonyms)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**. It's still the same game, just a different version. Plus, the tag stops being relevant once the next major version is released. There is no benefit to adding a snapshot tag, and it also adds additional work later.

Comment: Hm, fair enough. So what sort of additional work does it end up adding exactly, just to clarify?

Comment: @Texenox Removing the tag when the next major version releases. Since snapshot questions eventually become release version questions.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if that's the case about these questions. If the question describes a feature in that release version as working completely differently to how it works in the release version, and is written about it as being a question about a snapshot, that's not really the case. Is it?

Comment: @Texenox In that case the question is obsolete whatever tag you use and is probably better off deleted.

Comment: @Studoku +1 for reminding me that I need to consider things like that before asking on meta.